# Visual Studio 2022 installed. running Error. VS 2022. team_explorer.bat VsDevCmd.bat

Tags: windows, batch-file, visual-studio

**Installed Visual Studio 2022 Win 10 Home X64**

launching and Developer and whatever command of VS 2022 I get following **error**

```
**********************************************************************
** Visual Studio 2022 Developer Command Prompt v17.2.4
** Copyright (c) 2022 Microsoft Corporation
**********************************************************************
[ERROR:team_explorer.bat] Directory not found : "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer"

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools>
```

**Search the problem got me total headache.**

**1- Search Dir for team_explorer.bat Never found**

**2- Some web search lead me to test VsDevCmd.bat**

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\Common7\Tools\VsDevCmd.bat" -test
```

When I test it, giving following Error

```
**********************************************************************
[TEST:dotnet.bat] Checking for ilasm.exe...
[TEST:msbuild.bat] checking for msbuild.exe...
[TEST:winsdk.bat] Checking for 'signtool.exe'...
[TEST:winsdk.bat] Checking for 'ucrt.lib' in LIB...
[TEST:winsdk.bat] Checking for 'kernel32.lib' in LIB...
[TEST:winsdk.bat] Checking for 'corecrt.h' in INCLUDE...
[TEST:winsdk.bat] Checking for 'windows.h' in INCLUDE...
[TEST:cmake.bat] Checking for cmake.exe...
[TEST:cmake.bat] Checking for ninja.exe...
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\Common7\IDE\VC\Linux\bin\ConnectionManagerExe\ConnectionManager.exe
[TEST:netfxsdk.bat] Checking for ildasm.exe...
[TEST:netfxsdk.bat] Checking for sn.exe...
[TEST:team_explorer.bat] Testing for tf.exe...
[ERROR:team_explorer.bat] 'where tf.exe' failed
[TEST:testwindow.bat] Checking for vstest.console.exe...
[TEST:vcvars.bat] Checking for cl.exe...
[TEST:vcvars.bat] Checking for dumpbin.exe...
[TEST:vcvars.bat] Checking for msvcrt.lib in LIB...
[TEST:vcvars.bat] Checking for vcruntime.h in INCLUDE...
[ERROR:VsDevCmd.bat] *** VsDevCmd.bat encountered errors. Environment may be incomplete and/or incorrect. ***
[ERROR:VsDevCmd.bat] In an uninitialized command prompt, please 'set VSCMD_DEBUG=[value]' and then re-run
[ERROR:VsDevCmd.bat] vsdevcmd.bat [args] for additional details.
[ERROR:VsDevCmd.bat] Where [value] is:
[ERROR:VsDevCmd.bat]    1 : basic debug logging
[ERROR:VsDevCmd.bat]    2 : detailed debug logging
[ERROR:VsDevCmd.bat]    3 : trace level logging. Redirection of output to a file when using this level is recommended.
[ERROR:VsDevCmd.bat] Example: set VSCMD_DEBUG=3
[ERROR:VsDevCmd.bat]          vsdevcmd.bat > vsdevcmd.trace.txt 2>&1
```

**Finally How to fix This !?**

**3- Some web search says System Environment Var Path are not add.**

[https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/vs2017-developer-command-prompt-directory-not-foun/359683]

How and Where to add!?

I dont have Sys Env Var `VSINSTALLDIR` or `DevEnvDir` only Path and other non relative var

Under System Variable `Path` only have these

```
Path=
C:\windows\system32;C:\windows;C:\windows\System32\Wbem;
C:\windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;
C:\windows\System32\OpenSSH\;
C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39;
C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Scripts;
C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages;
C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;
C:\Program Files\Wolfram Research\WolframScript\;
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\150\Tools\Binn\;
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\170\Tools\Binn\;
C:\Program Files\dotnet\;
PATHEXT=.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC
```

**Finally**

**What and How to fix this problem!?**

**I need to know exactly what and how to do !?**

**Adding Var under system. What i name it !? and what file refers to !?**

**Mainly Errors Rising From**

```
team_explorer.bat
VsDevCmd.bat
```

***Appreciate the assistance***

Comment: I would perform a clean install of VS2022 and reinstall it.  Your system variables should have been updated when it was installed.  Be sure you install it as an Administrator

Comment: Thanks for helpful comment

Comment: Solved as @Ramhound pointed (clean install)
Thanks a lot

Comment: I reported this issue on developercommunity [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/VsDevCmdbat--Enter-VsDevShell-in-Build/10113562)

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this by going into the `BuildTools\Common7\Tools\vsdevcmd\ext` folder, and renaming `team_explorer.bat` to `team_explorer.bat.skip`.